# use boxplots to group observations per specimen across a numeric axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

i want to use the following table:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nstjjuwancgcksy/example.csv?dl=0

To make a plot similar to this one:

```
 ggplot(VMT, aes(x=as.factor(as.character(size)), y=VMT, group=specimen,color=method,fill=method)) + geom_boxplot()
```

However, there should be one boxplot per specimenANDmethod and each one of those should be filled with color according to method.

Anybody has a hint? 
Thanks in advance,
Agus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you asked

```
VMT$Spec.Method<-paste(as.character(VMT$specimen),as.character(VMT$method))
ggplot(VMT, aes(x=as.factor(as.character(size)),group=Spec.Method, y=VMT, fill=method)) + geom_boxplot() +
theme(text = element_text(size=10),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1))
```

Comment: Thanks Adiana! But still does not follows size in the x axis.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, if you have size in the x axis how can you visualize the different groups for combination of Specimen and method?

Comment: I thought that each specimen might have up to three different boxplots (number of methods levels) and colored according to method, and appearing in the plot ordered by size